Linq-to-SQL moving to EF Core, there is already an open DataReader associated with this command
UPDATE: This code is used in a server side data export process, so no UI that necessitates paging/chunking and I simply need to 'plow' through (up to) 100's of thousands of rows of data.
I'm migrating some legacy Linq-to-SQL code/queries to .NET 7 / EF Core. Some code that previously worked in L2S is now throwing the exception:

There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

I've dug around and have seen suggestions to enable MARS (but with serious consideration first) and have tried a few .Include statements that haven't helped.
I have a straight forward Profile (parent) -> HistoryData (child) table relationship. Where HistoryData.hispKey is foreign key to Profile.pKey.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group]
(
    [gKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [gName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    ....
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profile]
(
    [pKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pgKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pAuthID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [pDateUpdated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [pDateCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [pUpdatedBy] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [pCreatedBy] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
    [pProfile] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [pProfileXml] [xml] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistoryData]
(
    [hisKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [hisgKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [hispKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [hisType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [hisIndex] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [hisDateUpdated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [hisDateCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [hisUpdatedBy] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [hisCreatedBy] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [hisData] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [hisDataXml] [xml] NOT NULL
)

I then have the following projection statements that are identical to what I had in Linq-to-SQL (except obviously for the usage of a DbContext vs DataContext):
var profiles = dataContexts.xDS.Profiles
        .Where(p => p.GroupKey == gKey)
        .Where(p => options.AuthIdsToExport.Length == 0 || options.AuthIdsToExport.Contains(p.AuthID))
        .OrderBy(p => p.AuthID)
        .Select(p => new XmlProfileRow { 
            AuthId = p.AuthID, 
            Data = p.Data, 
            DataXml = p.ProfileXml, 
            DateCreated = p.DateCreated, 
            DateUpdated = p.DateUpdated 
        });
        
var historyDatas = dataContexts.xDS.HistoryDatas
        // .Include( h => h.Profile ) // This did not help
        .Where(h => h.GroupKey == gKey )
        .Where(h => options.AuthIdsToExport.Length == 0 || options.AuthIdsToExport.Contains(h.Profile!.AuthID))
        .OrderBy(h => h.Profile!.AuthID)
        .ThenBy(h => h.Type)
        .ThenBy(h => h.Index)
        .Select(h => new XmlHistoryRow { 
            AuthId = h.Profile!.AuthID, 
            DateCreated = h.DateCreated, 
            DateUpdated = h.DateUpdated, 
            Type = h.Type, 
            Index = h.Index, 
            Data = h.Data, 
            DataXml = h.DataXml 
        });

Using these two queries was originally written via IEnumerator objects and I am not sure if an EF Core 'Split Query' would help or not or something like Dappers 'multiple query' statement support, but I definitely can not have all data loaded into memory, I need to stream through the results of 'Profiles' and for each row, stream through results of 'History Data' for the currently 'related' rows.
The intent was to not have to issue new queries for each Profile's HistoryData rows.
Simplified code that demonstrates the problem is:
var profileEnumerator = profiles.GetEnumerator();
var historyEnumerator = historyDatas.GetEnumerator();
var currentHistory = historyEnumerator.MoveNext();
var currentProfile= profileEnumerator.MoveNext();

The final call, throws the exception with the call stack of:
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)  
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(Boolean isAsync, String method)  
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource'1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)  
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)  
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable'1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable'1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func'3 operation, Func'3 verifySucceeded)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable'1.Enumerator.MoveNext()  
at UserQuery.ExportDataAsync(String groupName, DataOptions options, DataContexts dataContexts), line 154  

What is the appropriate resolution to this when working in EF Core?
FYI, the generated SQL displayed up until point of exception is as follows (which seems correct):
info: 10/21/2024 10:30:59.384 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__gKey_0='1009' (Nullable = true)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [p].[pAuthID] AS [AuthId], [h].[hisDateCreated] AS [DateCreated], [h].[hisDateUpdated] AS [DateUpdated], [h].[hisType] AS [Type], [h].[hisIndex] AS [Index], [h].[hisData] AS [Data], [h].[hisDataXml] AS [DataXml]
      FROM [HistoryData] AS [h]
      LEFT JOIN [Profile] AS [p] ON [h].[hispKey] = [p].[pKey]
      WHERE [h].[hisgKey] = @__gKey_0
      ORDER BY [p].[pAuthID], [h].[hisType], [h].[hisIndex]
fail: 10/21/2024 10:30:59.385 RelationalEventId.CommandError[20102] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__gKey_0='1009' (Nullable = true)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [p].[pAuthID] AS [AuthId], [p].[pProfile] AS [Data], [p].[pProfileXml] AS [DataXml], [p].[pDateCreated] AS [DateCreated], [p].[pDateUpdated] AS [DateUpdated]
      FROM [Profile] AS [p]
      WHERE [p].[pgKey] = @__gKey_0
      ORDER BY [p].[pAuthID]


What is dataContexts.xDS?

DataContexts is just object with 4 different db/DbContext properties.  xDS is DbContext pointing to one sql database.  Also note, I've turned off change tracking for this code as well, not that I think it matters.

The problem with hidden code is that we can't see if it's about one context instance (looks like it) or a new context per call. It seems to me that you should use a new context for each query.

It is indeed one DbContext created and used for my queries (as I had done in L2S).  It is standard practice to make a new context every time you perform a query??  Seems aggressive, lol.  What if the DbContext was injected via DI but you had to run multiple queries?

You cannot have two active enumerators over the same connection, unless you activated MARS. It is strict DbConnection limitation.

I never saw a reason to "sort" before a "select", so I don't (is it smart enough to work with the "lesser data"?). And if I can't handle "realizing" an entire query, then I "chunk" (Page) it; instead of enumerating; which implies a lot of "unsteady state" in a client - server environment, IMO.

No, it's not standard practice to have one context per query, but neither is is recommended to have one context instance all the time. Anyway, it's not really clear if you actually enabled MARS. It should solve the problem. But if you didn't (or don't want to) then you could try using two context instances and, hence, two connections.

For this to work you would need to enable MultipleActiveResultSets, or collect the query results into lists, eg
var profiles = dataContexts.xDS.Profiles
        .Where(p => p.GroupKey == gKey)
        .Where(p => options.AuthIdsToExport.Length == 0 || options.AuthIdsToExport.Contains(p.AuthID))
        .OrderBy(p => p.AuthID)
        .Select(p => new XmlProfileRow { 
            AuthId = p.AuthID, 
            Data = p.Data, 
            DataXml = p.ProfileXml, 
            DateCreated = p.DateCreated, 
            DateUpdated = p.DateUpdated 
        }).ToList();


